# How to display a block-view with fields of a referenced entity when the referencing entity is view in full mode?

Tags: 7, entities, views

I think the question i got may not be hard to answer, but i'm struck and it seems i can't find any solution.

Basically, I want to build a block-view with some fields of a certain `node B` that is referenced from `node A` using an `entity-reference` field.

The problem shows some similarities with the one exposed at [a previous question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/32218/how-to-display-a-field-of-a-referenced-entity-in-views-contextual-block%20a%20previous%20question) but also some differences. Overall, I guess my problem should be solved without additional theming.

Right now I'm building a view that shows content of the content-type that `node B` has, and then i'm (mis)using a contextual filter (`entity-reference` field from node A) and a relationship (`referenced entity`).

It doesnt work, so I think i'm doing something in the wrong way.

What am i missing?

Thanks.